# Meaning of 最も多い in this sentence

Tags: grammar

> 毎年、日本で**最も多い**３万６０００人以上の人が走ります
>   Every year in Japan ??? more than 36,000 people run.

I can't understand at all what 最も多い does in this sentence. Literally it means 'most numerous' right? I can't understand it's meaning in this context or even how it fits in grammatically. Presumably it modifies 人 since that's the only available noun. But thereafter, I'm lost.

Comment: Is this about Tokyo Marathon?

Comment: Yes indeed. You're sensing a theme to my questions I see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this context, the following could safely be inferred.

「日本{にほん}で最{もっと}も多{おお}い」＝「日本のマラソン大会{たいかい}の中{なか}で最も多い」

What is 最も多い is the number of participants in the marathon.

> "Every year, over 36,000 people, which is the largest scale in Japan, run/participate."

A literal translation would be close to impossible, which is why I used "the largest scale".  A slightly more literal TL would be:

> "Every year, over 36,000 people, which is the most in Japan, run/participate (in this marathon)."

Comment: So the whole of 日本で最も多い actually modifies ３万６０００人以上. That makes sense, but I'd never have thought of it myself. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

最も多:
the most common 
the most popular
Ex: 日本で最も多い名前は鈴木です。
The most common name in Japan is Suzuki.

Comment: Well, I can see how that works in your example sentence, but I can't get it to make sense in my sentence. 'The most popular 36000 people'? That's a lot of popular people.